# How do I build the openSeaChest hard drive tools for Cygwin?

Tags: hard-drive, security, cygwin, sata, hdparm

As [detailed here](https://superuser.com/questions/1504761/why-is-hdparm-not-available-on-cygwin/1528867#1528867), the `hdparm` tool hasn't been actively maintained on Cygwin for some time. This results in a situation in which there is no current tool that can perform the firmware-level Secure Erase and Block Erase ATA commands that instruct a PATA or SATA drive's firmware to erase the drive.

These firmware-level erases are widely considered the most secure and reliable way to wipe modern drives - and on SSDs, the *only* secure way to do so because features like wear levelling make normal zero-filling unreliable. Essentially, this means that - on Cygwin at least - there is currently *no way* to securely wipe an SSD.

Amidst this state of affairs, I recently came across the [openSeaChest](https://github.com/Seagate/openSeaChest) set of utilities, developed at Seagate but open-sourced and designed to work with any  SATA, SAS or NVMe drives. [openSeaChest seems positioned](https://www.snia.org/educational-library/whats-better-sg3utils-hdparm-sdparm-2018) to be able to replace tools like `hdparm` and `sg3_utils`, and can be used to run ATA firmware commands like Secure Erase and Block Erase in addition to a lot more.

How do I build the latest version of the suite so that I can use its binaries in Cygwin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Compile the openSeaChest utilities for Cygwin and Windows

- Install [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) and run the MSYS2 MinGW 64-bit terminal
- Run `pacman -Syu` and install any updates, ignoring any warnings about Cygwin.dll mismatches
- Open the MSYS2 MinGW 64-bit terminal again and run `pacman -Syu` once more
- Get the minGW-w64 toolchain for compiling minGW w64 programs:

  ```
  pacman -S --needed base-devel mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain
  ```

  When asked which packages to install, enter all of the packages as a range. For example, if the highest package listed is 19, enter `1-19`.
- Add `C:\msys64\usr\bin` and `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin` to your Windows PATH (you may need to reboot)
- Get `git` and its dependencies:

  ```
  pacman -S --needed git
  ```
- Get a list of the project's current branches:

  ```
  git ls-remote --heads https://github.com/Seagate/openSeaChest.git | sed 's?.*refs/heads/??'
  ```
- To clone the `release/Release-20.11` branch and `cd` into it (replace with your chosen branch):

  ```
  git clone --recurse-submodules  --branch release/Release-20.11 --single-branch  https://github.com/Seagate/openSeaChest.git openSeaChest && cd openseaChest
  ```
- Fetch and update each submodule:

  ```
  git submodule foreach 'git config remote.origin.fetch refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*'
  git submodule foreach 'git fetch'
  git submodule foreach --recursive 'git checkout release/Release-20.11'
  ```
- Finally, enter the `Make/gccWin/` directory and start building the utilities:

  ```
  cd Make/gccWin/ && make -f Makefile.gccWin
  ```

The compiled executables will be located in the `openseachest_exes` directory. You can safely delete all of the files with numbers suffixed to the end of them - this is [an outdated step](https://github.com/Seagate/openSeaChest/issues/44#issuecomment-755448604) of the build process created by the original developer and intended to be removed soon.

To use the remaining binaries, move them to somewhere in your Cygwin PATH such as `/usr/local/bin`. I also recommend [renaming](https://serverfault.com/a/228759/329607) them from the long-winded *openSeaChest_* to something like this:

```
$ ls     

openSeaChest_Basics.exe
openSeaChest_Configure.exe
openSeaChest_Erase.exe
openSeaChest_Firmware.exe
openSeaChest_Format.exe
openSeaChest_GenericTests.exe
openSeaChest_Info.exe
openSeaChest_Logs.exe
openSeaChest_NVMe.exe
openSeaChest_PassthroughTest.exe
openSeaChest_PowerControl.exe
openSeaChest_SMART.exe
openSeaChest_ZBD.exe

$ rename "openSeaChest" "osc" *.exe

osc_Basics.exe
osc_Configure.exe
osc_Erase.exe
osc_Firmware.exe
osc_Format.exe
osc_GenericTests.exe
osc_Info.exe
osc_Logs.exe
osc_NVMe.exe
osc_PassthroughTest.exe
osc_PowerControl.exe
osc_SMART.exe
osc_ZBD.exe
```